Invoice updating with line items
I am building a clinic referral system that will be used to generate referrals which in turn is i used to generate an invoice. Am able to do CRUD operations for referrals now for invoices the Update is giving me issues.
The following are my models:


class Invoice(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = [
        ('Medicine', 'Medicine'),
        ('Auxillary', 'Auxillary'),
        ('Mixed', 'Mixed'),
    ]

    patient = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='inv', blank=True, null=True)
    reference = models.OneToOneField(Referral, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='invoice', null=True)
    invoice_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default='Medicine')
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    due_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    prepared_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='prepared_invoices', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.patient.first_name) + " " + str(self.patient.last_name)
    
    def total_amount(self):
        tax_rate = 10
        subtotal = sum(item.amount for item in self.lineitems.all())
        tax_amount = (subtotal * tax_rate) / 100  # Calculate tax amount
        return subtotal + tax_amount
    
    def get_status(self):
        return self.status

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id and not self.due_date:
            self.due_date = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=15)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        

class LineItem(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lineitems', blank=True, null=True)
    service = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.invoice)



my views:


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class CreateInvoiceView(UserPassesTestMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'referral/invoice_create.html'
    form_class = BillInvoiceForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('ereferral:invoice-list')

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_superuser
    
    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        patient_id = self.kwargs.get('patient_id')
        referral_id = self.kwargs.get('referral_id')

        patient = get_object_or_404(User, id=patient_id)
        referral = get_object_or_404(Referral, id=referral_id)

        initial['patient'] = patient
        initial['reference'] = referral

        return initial

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['formset'] = LineItemFormset(self.request.POST)
        else:
            context['formset'] = LineItemFormset()
        context['title'] = 'Invoice Generator'
        return context
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formset = context['formset']
        if formset.is_valid():
            try:
                invoice = form.save(commit=False)
                invoice.save()  # Save to get the primary key value

                total = 0
                for item_form in formset:
                    if item_form.cleaned_data:  # Ensure we are not processing empty forms
                        service = item_form.cleaned_data.get('service')
                        description = item_form.cleaned_data.get('description')
                        quantity = item_form.cleaned_data.get('quantity')
                        rate = item_form.cleaned_data.get('rate')
                        if service and description and quantity and rate:
                            amount = float(rate) * float(quantity)
                            total += amount
                            LineItem.objects.create(
                                invoice=invoice,
                                service=service,
                                description=description,
                                quantity=quantity,
                                rate=rate,
                                amount=amount
                            )
                invoice.total_amount = total
                invoice.save()

                try:
                    generate_PDF(self.request, id=invoice.id)
                except Exception as e:
                    logger.error(f"Error generating PDF: {e}")

                return redirect(self.success_url)
            except ValidationError as e:
                error_message = str(e)
                messages.error(self.request, error_message)  # Add error message to Django messages framework
                context['error_message'] = error_message  # Pass error message to context for rendering in template
                return render(self.request, self.template_name, context)
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f"Error saving invoice or line items: {e}")
                return self.form_invalid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
        
  
def view_PDF(request, id=None):
    TAX_RATE = Decimal('0.10')  # Define the tax rate, e.g., 10%

    invoice = get_object_or_404(Invoice, id=id)
    lineitems = invoice.lineitems.all()
    lineitems_total = sum(item.amount for item in lineitems)  # Calculate the total amount
    tax_amount = lineitems_total * TAX_RATE  # Calculate the tax amount
    grand_total = lineitems_total + tax_amount  # Calculate the final total including tax
    print("Total: ", grand_total)


    context = {
        "company": {
            "name": request.user.username,
            "role" :request.user.userprofile.role,
            "identifier": request.user.userprofile.id_number,
            "phone": request.user.userprofile.phone,
            "email": request.user.email,
        },
        
        "invoice_id": invoice.id,
        "date": invoice.date,
        "lineitems_total": lineitems_total,  # Use calculated total
        "tax_amount": tax_amount,  # Tax amount
        "grand_total": grand_total,  # Total amount including tax
        #"invoice_total": invoice.amount,
        "patient": invoice.patient,
        "lineitem": lineitems,

    }
    return render(request, 'referral/invoice_template.html', context)


def generate_PDF(request, id):
    try:
        url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('ereferral:invoice-detail', args=[id]))
        pdf = pdfkit.from_url(url, False)

        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="invoice.pdf"'
        response.write(pdf)
        
        return response
    except ValidationError:
        # Handle invalid URL
        return HttpResponse("Invalid URL provided.")
    except Exception as e:
        # Handle other exceptions
        return HttpResponse(f"Error generating PDF: {escape(str(e))}")

def change_status(request):
    return redirect('referral:invoice-list')

def view_404(request,  *args, **kwargs):

    return redirect('referral:invoice-list')



class InvoiceUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Invoice
    form_class = BillInvoiceForm
    template_name = 'referral/invoice_create.html'  # Update with your template name
    success_url = reverse_lazy('invoice-list')  # Update with your success URL name

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_superuser

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        line_items = LineItem.objects.filter(invoice=self.object)  # Fetch existing line items
        initial['line_items'] = [{'service': item.service, 'description': item.description, 'quantity': item.quantity, 'rate': item.rate} for item in line_items]
        return initial

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        LineItemFormset = formset_factory(LineItemForm, extra=1)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['formset'] = LineItemFormset(self.request.POST, initial=self.get_initial())
        else:
            context['formset'] = LineItemFormset(initial=self.get_initial())
        context['title'] = 'Edit Invoice'
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formset = context['formset']
        if formset.is_valid():
            try:
                invoice = form.save(commit=False)
                invoice.save()  # Save to get the primary key value

                total = 0
                LineItem.objects.filter(invoice=invoice).delete()  # Delete existing line items

                for item_form in formset:
                    if item_form.cleaned_data:  # Ensure we are not processing empty forms
                        service = item_form.cleaned_data.get('service')
                        description = item_form.cleaned_data.get('description')
                        quantity = item_form.cleaned_data.get('quantity')
                        rate = item_form.cleaned_data.get('rate')
                        if service and description and quantity and rate:
                            amount = float(rate) * float(quantity)
                            total += amount
                            LineItem.objects.create(
                                invoice=invoice,
                                service=service,
                                description=description,
                                quantity=quantity,
                                rate=rate,
                                amount=amount
                            )
                invoice.total_amount = total
                invoice.save()

                return super().form_valid(form)
            except Exception as e:
                # Handle any errors here
                return self.form_invalid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
        



my  templates:

invoice_list.html

{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load bulma_tags %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %} Invoice {% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                {{ message }}
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h4>All Invoices</h4>
          <hr>
        </div>
      </div>

    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'ereferral:invoice-list' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
            <div class="card">
                
                <div class="card-header">
                    <span><i class="bi bi-table me-2"></i></span> Invoice Data
                </div>
                
                <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="example" class="table table-striped data-table" style="width: 100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            {% if request.user.userprofile.role == "Referral Provider" %}
                                <th></th>
                            {% endif %}
                            <th>Invoice</th>
                            <th>Patient</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Due Date</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for invoice in invoices %}
                        <tr>
                            {% if request.user.userprofile.role == "Referral Provider" %}
                                <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="{{invoice.id}}" name="invoice_id" size="1" /></td>
                            {% endif %}
                            <td width="2%">CBU00{{invoice.id}}</td>
                            <td width="15%">{{invoice.patient.first_name }} {{invoice.patient.last_name }}</td>
                            <td> {{invoice.date}} </td>
                            <td> {{invoice.due_date}} </td>
                            <td> {{invoice.total_amount}} </td>
                            
                            <td >
                                {% if invoice.get_status %}
                                <a class="button is-small is-success" href="#" style="text-decoration: none; font-weight: bolder;">Paid</a>
                                {% else %}
                                <a class="button is-small is-warning" href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(233, 13, 31); font-weight: bolder;">Not Paid</a>
                                {% endif %}
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <a href="{% url 'ereferral:invoice-update' pk=invoice.id %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary">
                                    <i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i>
                                </a>

                                <a href="{% url 'ereferral:invoice-detail' id=invoice.id %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info" target="_blank">
                                    <i class="bi bi-binoculars"></i>
                                </a>

                                <a href="{% url 'ereferral:invoice-download' id=invoice.id %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">
                                    <i class="bi bi-download"></i>
                                </a>

                                <a href="{% url 'ereferral:invoice-delete' pk=invoice.id %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">
                                    <i class="bi bi-trash"></i>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                        
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            {% if request.user.userprofile.role == "Referral Provider" %}
                                <th></th>
                            {% endif %}
                            <th>Invoice</th>
                            <th>Patient</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Due Date</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        {% if request.user.userprofile.role == "Referral Provider" %}
            <div class="card has-background-white-ter">
                <header class="card-header">
                    <p class="card-header-title">
                        Change Status
                    </p>
                </header>
                <div class="card-content mb-4">
                    <div class="select is-rounded mt-2">
                        <select id="status" name="status">
                            <option value="1">Paid</option>
                            <option value="0">Not Paid</option>
                        </select>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" id="change-status-button" type="submit" name="mybtn">
                            <i class="bi bi-pencil-square change-status-button"></i> Change
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    </form>

    
{% endblock content %}


invoice_create.html

{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load bulma_tags %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %} Create Invoice {% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

    {% if error_message %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        {{ error_message }}
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    <br>
    

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header text-center">
            <h4>INVOICE</h4>
        </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="hero-body">
                    <form class="" method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" >Patient</span>
                                    {{form.patient}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" >Reference</span>
                                    {{form.reference}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" >Invoice Type</span>
                                    {{form.invoice_type}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            
                                <thead class="table-success">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Product/Service</th>
                                        <th>Description</th>
                                        <th >QTY</th>
                                        <th>RATE</th>
                                        <th>AMOUNTK</th>
                                        <th>ADD</th>
                                </thead>        
                                <tbody>
                                    </tr>
                                    {{ formset.management_form }}
                                    {% for frm in formset %}
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{frm.service}}</td>
                                        <td>{{frm.description}}</td>
                                        <td>{{frm.quantity}}</td>
                                        <td>{{frm.rate}}</td>
                                        <td class="amount"></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                                <button
                                                    class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success add-form-row">+</button>&nbsp;
                                                <!-- <button class="button is-small btn btn-warning remove-form-row">-</button> -->
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                
                                </tbody>

                        </table>
                        
                        <br>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <h3 class="title is-4">Total(ZMW): <span id="total" ></span></h3>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <hr>

                        <div class="row mb-2">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-floppy" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M11 2H9v3h2z"/>
                                    <path d="M1.5 0h11.586a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.06.44l1.415 1.414A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 16 2.914V14.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5h-13A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 14.5v-13A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.5 0M1 1.5v13a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5H2v-4.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3.5 9h9a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.5 1.5V15h.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5V2.914a.5.5 0 0 0-.146-.353l-1.415-1.415A.5.5 0 0 0 13.086 1H13v4.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.5 7h-7A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 5.5V1H1.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5m3 4a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h7a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5V1H4zM3 15h10v-4.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-9a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5z"/>
                                  </svg> Create
                              </button>
                    
                              <a href="{% url 'ereferral:invoice-list' %}" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm">
                                <i class="bi bi-arrow-return-left"></i> Invoices
                              </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    
{% endblock %}


SO WHEN I TRY TO UPDATE THE INVOICE AN GETTING THE ERROR :
In the browser:
KeyError at /ereferral/invoices/31/update/
0

Request Method:GETRequest URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/ereferral/invoices/31/update/Django Version:4.2.11Exception Type:KeyErrorException Value:0Exception Location:/home/kennerdol/Desktop/BSc Infor Tech/Level 10/Final Year Project/Practical Project/BIT590_Virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py, line 236, in _construct_formRaised during:eReferral_App.views.InvoiceUpdateViewPython Executable:/home/kennerdol/Desktop/BSc Infor Tech/Level 10/Final Year Project/Practical Project/BIT590_Virt/bin/python3Python Version:3.8.10Python Path:['/home/kennerdol/Desktop/BSc Infor Tech/Level 10/Final Year Project/Practical ' 'Project/IERBS_Project', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/kennerdol/Desktop/BSc Infor Tech/Level 10/Final Year Project/Practical ' 'Project/BIT590_Virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages']Server time:Wed, 19 Jun 2024 11:02:05 +0000
Error during template rendering
In template /home/kennerdol/Desktop/BSc Infor Tech/Level 10/Final Year Project/Practical Project/IERBS_Project/templates/referral/invoice_create.html, error at line 61
0
51<th>Product/Service</th>52<th>Description</th>53<th >QTY</th>54<th>RATE</th>55<th>AMOUNTK</th>56<th>ADD</th>57</thead>58<tbody>59</tr>60{{ formset.management_form }}61{% for frm in formset %}62<tr>63<td>{{frm.service}}</td>64<td>{{frm.description}}</td>65<td>{{frm.quantity}}</td>66<td>{{frm.rate}}</td>67<td class="amount"></td>68<td>69<div class="input-group-append">70<button71class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success add-form-row">+</button> 
I have tried to review the code but i cant seem to find any were to make changes, which am still doing now.
